# how to set UITableviewcell or UITableview as Empty?

Tags: iphone

i am using rss feed.first time ,table view has no rows.if i press button, there will come values.if i press again ,the table view has previous values.after recieving data it disappears and new data will come there.but when i press button ,there cannot be previous value.i want to
remove it.How can i do it? any help?

Comment: You've asked 21 questions and accepted 0 of them. You should go back and accept some answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to update the contents of your UITableView call `[tableView reloadData]` method. So if by that time you've cleared your previous data from your data source then the table must get empty.

Comment: No. i tried it.suppose if  the table has value from one url.if click
the BUTTON ,it will communicate same url,at that time there is no update,previoue values are there....

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code... If previous values still are in the table it must mean that you have not cleared your data source

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView works by a datasource. I'm going to assume that you have followed Apple's way of setting up a tableview which should look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{   
    static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_tableViewData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

In this example the data for the UITableView is stored in the tableViewData array. Which is initialized like:

```
_tableViewData = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cell 1", @"cell 2", @"cell 3", @"cell 4", nil] retain];
```

So when you want to update the values of the tableview to something new you need to change the value of the tableViewData array and call reloadData on the table view.

```
_tableViewData = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"new cell 1" , @"new cell 2", @"new cell 3", @"new cell 4", nil] retain];
[_tableView reloadData];
```